# why the table schema disappears when I use @Column Annotation in java spring boot / sprng data jpa

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I newly start learn java and spring boot , I faced a problem while I am watching sping data jpa for Nelson in youtube is that when I use @Column Annotation the table schema is disappear from the database

Comment: I don't understand your question. What disappears?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.